# Ajax json into for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Here is the ajax function which is run when page loads

```
var data;

    window.onload= function(){

        $.ajax({
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(string) {
            data = $.parseJSON(string);
        },
        url: 'user_data.json'
    });
        createSideMenu();
    }
```

This is the inside of the JSON file:

```
{"sunnipaevad":[
    {"mati_sunnipaev":[
        {"kulalised" : [ 
            {"name":"Anti", 
            "e_mail":"anti@gmail.com", 
            "salasona":"Aa123456", 
            "kontonumber":"123456"} ]},
        {"veebileht" : [
            {"asukoht":[
                {"aadress":"Kakumae 5",
                "google_maps":"asd"}
            ]}
        ]}
    ],
    "kati_sunnipaev":[
        {"kulalised" : [ 
            {"name":"Anti", 
            "e_mail":"kati@gmail.com", 
            "salasona":"Aa123456", 
            "kontonumber":"123456"} ]},
        {"veebileht" : [
            {"asukoht":[
                {"aadress":"Kakumae 5",
                "google_maps":"asd"}
            ]}
        ]}
    ]}
]}
```

I am not sure why this is not working:

```
alert(data.sunnipaevad[0].kulalised[0].name);
```

I have tried many things and not a single one has worked.

Comment: `data.sunnipaevad[0].mati_sunnipaev[0].kulalised[0].name` or `data.sunnipaevad[0].kati_sunnipaev[0].kulalised[0].name`

Answer (score 0):

Where do you call the alert? In your function createSideMenu()? Then you must wait the request with the json. Try this:

```
…
success: function(string) {
    data = $.parseJSON(string);
    createSideMenu();
},
…
```

Ciao
Ralf

Comment: Alert is called in another function, "data" is a global variable.

Comment: But you must wait for the request. No successful request, no data.

Answer (score 0):

First, replace:

```
dataType: 'text',
```

with:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

and remove the `$.parseJSON`

then check the content with `console.log(data)`

```
window.onload= function(){

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        url: 'user_data.json'
    });
    createSideMenu();
}
```

Here, you will be able to see in your browser console the data objet or see if the request failed.